# When to make multiple packages or data flow task in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package, dataflow

I'm sorry if this a dumb question, as I can't seem to find the answer on google maybe because other people think it's obvious, but I'm a bit a confused beginner.

So, I'm practicing to make a small data warehouse.
I have the following packages in SSIS:
1. Copy from operational database to archive database
2. Copy from archive to staging area
3. Transformations in staging area and put into data warehouse

These packages are controlled by jobs in SQL Server.

I figured it would be also possible to have only one package and put all 1-2-3 as separate data flow tasks into that package. I started to wonder about this because all task only have one data flow task in it (in the data flow task itself there are many source-destination stuff going on though).

What are best practices for this? When do you make different packages and when multiple data flow tasks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rather a matter of personal taste. Personally, I would prefer to keep them separated for several reasons, including but not limited to:

- If a package #2 breaks at some point because of schema drift or something, package #3 will still work normally (for some tables, at least).
- In a team, it's better to keep things small because several people might need to check out different packages from CVS to work on them simultaneously. It will be simply impossible if everything is located within a single gigantic package.
- When a warehouse becomes large enough (hundreds of tables) it is often practical to split each stage between several packages - say, one for each data source / subject area. It makes easier not to get lost in them.

Besides, large SSIS packages are quite unwieldy - I remember working with one that weighs ~30 Mb, it was a real pain in the rear.

Comment: Also by splitting into multiple packages, you have the ability to run them concurrently (assuming different focus areas). Just by changing our dimension load from purely serial package execution to a mix of parallel containers running serial executions, our load time dropped dramatically.

Comment: @billinkc, yes, but it's not always possible. For example, different packages might update the same lookup tables.

Comment: Which is where you'd impose ordering on package execution through serial execution. I'm not disputing your answer, just providing an additional point of why small, tightly focused packages lend themselves well to problem solving

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is also possible to run several simultaneous dataflows in a single package :) Though it would be a noticeably less flexible solution, of course.